# array content changed after returning from a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the following program, I try to pass an array into a function, return it as a pointer, and print out the value.

```
int* assign(int* ptr2){
  int temp[6];
  for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
    temp[i] = *ptr2++;
  ptr2 = temp;
  printf("addr:%p \n",ptr2);
  for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%d ",*ptr2++);
  printf("\n");
  ptr2=temp;
  return ptr2;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
  int ele[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int *ptr;
  ptr = assign(ele);
  printf("addr:%p \n",ptr);
  for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%d ",*ptr++);
  getchar();
  return 0; 
}
```

Here is the output:

```
addr:0020F7D0
1 2 3 4 5 6
addr:0020F7D0
2160632 2 3 2160698 25558054 1277364467
```

The value is correct within the "assign" function but gone wrong in the main function.
It is strange because both ptr2 and ptr pointed to the same address, so what is the problem here?

Comment: You should format your code.

Answer (score 2):

Lets illustrate what happens here:

In `main`:

```
ele: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

In `assign`:

```
ptr2 => ele (passed argument)
tmp: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} (copied from ptr2 => ele)
ptr2 => tmp (local array)
<printing tmp>
return ptr2 => tmp
<tmp becomes invalid (assign ended)>
```

Back to `main`:

```
ptr => tmp (from assign, but invalid!)
<printing ptr: undefined behaviour>
```

Now `ptr2` points to `tmp`, a variable local to `assign`. Remember, local variables go out of scope and become invalid when the block they are local to ends. So `ptr` in `main` points to some memory that became invalid when `assign` ended and you end up with garbage being printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of the local variable `temp`, after assigning it to `ptr2`. The memory for `temp` is cleaned up at the end of the `assign` function when it goes out of scope and is therefore no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing:

```
int temp[6];
```

in the function `assign`, you have just created a local variable in the current scope, store in the stack. So as soon as the function is over, you are out of the scope and the variable is removed of the stack.

Then, `ptr2` contains the adress of a variable which does not exist anymore.